# Insert formatted Excel Pivot Table into Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, export, pivot-table, bookmarks

I made a template in Word where I have placed bookmarks. My idea was to export from Excel directly to this template.

On a weekly basis I import data from CSV to a constant Excel template. I export data from Excel to a Word document which is a template with selected areas where data is inserted.

This process works but I am tired of my pivot tables being imported with visible filters (filters in pivot tables are placed above even pivot tables). I delete these lines manually in Word. This in itself is not a huge problem, but I'm sure this can be solved automatically so that the pivot tables are imported without this "filter line".

I found code on the web which inserts my pivot table the way I would like it. I am not competent enough to rewrite my code.

The code below inserts the pivot table:

```
Sub PivotTablePaste ()
    Dim SourcePivottable As PivotTable
    Dim DestinationRange As Range
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    Set SourcePivottable = Worksheets ("Sheet1"). PivotTables (1)
    Set DestinationRange = Worksheets ("Sheet1"). Range ("P1")
    
    'Copy TableRange1
    SourcePivottable.TableRange1.Copy
    With DestinationRange.Offset (_
      SourcePivottable.TableRange1.Row - SourcePivottable.TableRange2.Row, 0)
        .PasteSpecial Paste: = xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste: = xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste: = xlPasteColumnWidths
    End With
    
    'Copy everything above TableRange1 cell-by-cell
    For Each aCell In SourcePivottable.TableRange2.Cells
        If Not Intersect (aCell, SourcePivottable.TableRange1) Is Nothing Then Exit For
        aCell.Copy
        With DestinationRange.Offset (_
          aCell.Row - SourcePivottable.TableRange2.Row, _
          aCell.Column - SourcePivottable.TableRange2.Column)
            .PasteSpecial Paste: = xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial Paste: = xlPasteFormats
        End With
    Next aCell
    
End Sub
```

This code is my own and inserts the parts from Excel to Word perfectly, except for the visible filter line from the Pivot Table.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateBasicWordReport()

Dim Wdapp As Object
Dim savename As String
Dim FileXt As String

Set Wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With Wdapp
'.Visible = True
'.Activate

.Documents.Add "C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\notattest\Ændringsnotat.docx"

Dim ws As Worksheet

Copy to clipboard
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
Sheets("Eksport - Opsummering").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
Selection.Copy
.Selection.Goto what:=-1, Name:="Styklistefase1"
.Selection.Paste
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
Sheets("Eksport - Opsummering").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
Selection.Copy
.Selection.Goto what:=-1, Name:="Styklistefase1a"
.Selection.Paste

savename = Environ("userProfile") & "\Desktop\Exceltest\Export-Ændringsnotat " & _
Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & ".docx"

.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 savename

.ActiveDocument.Close
.Quit

End With

Set Wdapp = Nothing
```